# laravel mass form field creation

Tags: php, laravel

I need to create both create and edit views for a database table that has 135 columns. I think writing these fields might just give me grey hairs far sooner than I feel comfortable with so I really hope there's some kind of method to generating a form based on a database table. I know cakePHP's bake utility could do this, but I haven't found something similar for Laravel.
The only things I have found that come close are the Way/Generators and Ddollars/generators packages on github, but these generate forms based on a list of fields as a commandline argument, not a table definition. Is there anyone here who can give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: $cols = Schema::getColumnListing('table');

Comment: That gives me the list of fields, yes. How would that help me though? Create a route to print these and paste them into a generator command?

Comment: I think, view generating is not good solution.
For example, you can create some trait, which help to iterate(in view template) through all fields in table(model).

Comment: I've never worked with traits in the past, so wouldn't have any clue on how to even begin to do that... its just a big table with a very large amount of fields , the HTML of which needs to be styleable later. So I assumed generating a form would be the best solution here. Do you not agree?

Comment: Benefit of this approach is what you can customize all 135 inputs in one place. It's more flexible.
Trait it is only method(s) which you cat use in many models without  code repeating. Of course, you can do this without traits.

`
...
static function iterateCols() {
   // $this->table must be defined
   return Schema::getColumnListing($this->table);
}
...
`
and in view:

`
foreach (ModelName::iterateCols() as $k..)

`

Comment: That works, but the form needs to later be split into a number of collapseable regions in the view layer. Wouldn't make this approach make that impossible? You can't influence the HTML that is being written here , you somehow have to 'if' your way through making regions. I like your approach, I just don't think the folks who have to style the stuff afterwards will :)

Comment: You can prepare fields in controller:  

`
$fields = ModelName::iterateCols();  
//and separate them  
$fields = array_chunk($fields, 10);  
return View::make('test', ['flds' => $fields])  
  
...  
  
@foreach($flds as $key)  
  <custom>{{ $table_model_row[$key] }}</custom>  
@endforeach  
`

Comment: note, $key is chunk from 10 keys...

Comment: Hmm, I think I can work with that. I can't mark it as an answer since it's a comment though, can I?